# Why all Avatar's and Grantha's references happened only in India and not elsewhere?

Tags: avatars, india, gods

This is more merely an outside question. Many have a conscious feeling that why all Devas, Avataras and incidents written on our text books are confined to Indian Mediterranean, mostly North region of India?

The spread through mapping seems to start from Afghanistan (*Gandhar*) and ending to Uttar Pradesh (Indian state), as what there current names.

If I take a look at the mapping, the most conscious is Shiva, who resided in Himalayas (Peculiarly), but there being thousands of mountains around the world.

Similarly Rama took avatar in *Ayodhya* which is the northern part of India, but not in any other country.

Even most of the mythological history seems to revolve around Northern Part of India only, leaving Ramayana which includes Sri Lanka as a core part.

Comment: Just a food for thought: perhaps those happenings in India were recorded in India , while those happenings of Avatars outside India were ...  recorded outside India and over time they fructified into their own religion? This is because all religions support the same base argument, and contain very similar stories, but due to interpretations over numerous decades the final version does not seem to be simliar.

Comment: anybody interested and willing to consider this topic can do more research and post as an answer. i avoided because this does not seem to be a direct answer in any way to the question. Just some thing to think

Comment: According to you it is mythology. So it doesn't deserve anserwing and why are you seeking an answer for mythology?

Comment: @Sai, I'm not with you, I think I have the answer, but I am searching for valid resourced to make it more believable for others.

Comment: @Wisdom Mythology is not being used pejoratively.  See my answer to your meta question: http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/293/36

Comment: We simply do not if there were or were not any avatars outside of India.

Answer (score 11):

There are many references which point towards places outside India. But the names are contemporary to puranas so the names are obviously in Sanskrit.

In Vaaman Purana, it is said that Vaaman or Vishnu placed a Trident on a mountain to define the boundary of east direction. (It is also repeated in Kishkindha Kand of Ramayana). This trident is Paracas Candelabra of Peru. The patal to which Bali goes is claimed as South America by P N Oak. Kalyavan from Mahabharata is also claimed by Shivaji Sawant in his book to be Yavan (Ionian or Greek).

We need to find such unexplained places outside India also. (For e.g. Places from Patal like Bhogawati, Tribhuvanak Nagariust be searched in South America. They are claimed by P N Oak and Anil Patil as Bogota and Tiahuanaco)

Now, before and after Ravana, India has been a superpower in the world. Main goal of Ramayana was to establish Ayodhya's supremacy over powerful Lankan empire. As victory is written by the victor, we can see heroes from India and villains from other countries - Ravan, Kalyavan, etc.

Comment: Did you find a reference in the Kishkindha Kanda?

Comment: Ramayana Kishkindha kand 40/53-54. त्रिशिराः कांचनः केतुस्तालस्य च महात्मनः| स्थापितः पर्वतस्याग्रे विराजती सवेदिकः|| पूर्वस्यां दिशि निर्माणं कृतं तत् त्रिदशेश्वरैः| ततः परं हेममयः श्रीमानुदयपर्वतः||

Comment: Verses 53-54 don't mention Vamana or Vishnu at all: http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga40/kishkindhasans40.htm#Verse58

Comment: Yes but it is established by Vishnu as given in Vaaman Purana

Comment: 4/40-52 refers Vishnu

Comment: @ShreemayPanhalhar Verse 52 talks about the serpent Adiseshan, it doesn't mention Vishnu doing anything.