# Why most of places Lord Shiva visited during Earth tour belongs to places in Nepal and India?

Tags: shiva

I have listen **Swasthani** a lot of times. When lord shiva visited earth with dead body of satidevi, The places visited by him are currently in Nepal and India. What's reason behind this, I know hindu is oldest religion. But, at the time Earth belongs to only current Asia ?

Comment: IMO He was just trying to visit close to the home/Place where Mata Sati used to live i.e. Kailash or her birth place. It is just an opinion though.

Comment: That's one of the possible case. I wonder about the where are the all other places in current world, places other than Nepal/India doesn't exist at that time ?

Comment: Related: [Why all Avatar's and Grantha's references happened only in India and not elsewhere?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/why-all-avatars-and-granthas-references-happened-only-in-india-and-not-elsewhe)

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Interesting over there question was similar. But no strong point for existence of outside South Asia.

Comment: The burning of Sati event took place in previous kalpa.. ie. It was in previous creation....

Comment: In my opinion, it is because that particulair cluster of countries is to the world what the heart is to the human body. And Hinduism often sees the heart as the seat of the intellect, so it would make sense to me that most activity (eg. incarnations) happen there.

Comment: @Sagar Gautam Welcome to Hinduism SE.. I think you are from Nepal (I'm also from Nepal)... btw regarding Swasthani Vrata Katha the text claims that it is part of Skandha Purana... but I have searched many parts of Skandha Purana and I haven't become able to find it... so it maybe just a regional version too.. also Swasthani is only known in Nepal, people in India do not know about Swasthani Vrata Katha...

Comment: @Tezz That might be true, every year when I listen this then I wonder every time

Comment: because Bharatha Varsha is land of Sanatana Dharma, Rishis and Bhagavatas. Obviously we will only visit homes of friends who like to meet us, not strangers who don't care about us or dislike us. So God visits places where his devotees live, which is mostly Bharat

Comment: @ram This might be a solid reason.