# Did Lord Vishnu have any avatar in other parts of world as well?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, avatars

People believe Krishna was God. And it's not a fiction, it was reality.

So when it's reality, we must admit he saw whole world by same eyes. *And he is/was Dharma*. He is/was everything.

Personally I believe God can't do partiality. And God can't be just for Hindus.

So is there any evidence/book source where his avatar or stories are mentioned in other parts of world in history?

Comment: Are you asking if Vishnu had any avatar as a [mleccha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mleccha)?

Comment: "People believe Krishna was God" no most people do not. "And it's not a fiction, it was reality." How do you know this? "So  is there any evidence/book source where his avatar or stories are mentioned in other parts of world in history?" No but there are refences in the Bible and the quran about the Kalki avatar and this is not certain.

Comment: Related or Possibly Duplicate - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/why-all-avatars-and-granthas-references-happened-only-in-india-and-not-elsewhe

Comment: ISKCON says Vishnu incarnated as Jesus.

Comment: @Ikshvaku I don't believe that.

Comment: @sv. I mean this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/why-all-avatars-and-granthas-references-happened-only-in-india-and-not-elsewhe

Comment: Simple answer is Hindu gods just love Bharata-varsha. If you go into details, you'll end up finding some pretty rude things about Mlecchas (foreigners) like they're treated on par with outcastes with labels such as barbarians, uncivilized, etc. So think about it, how can a Hindu god take birth in a foreign land and be called a mleccha?

Comment: @sv. Let's not talk about mleccha. I don't know mleccha.

Comment: What do you mean by Hindu gods? God is one.

Comment: 'mleccha' means foreigner. And 'mleccha desha' means foreign country i.e., any country other than India/Bharata-varsha. So you should rephrase your question to '...any avatar in mleccha desha (foreign country)'. 'What do you mean by Hindu gods? God is one.' - if God is one, why did you call him Vishnu? Why not Shiva?

Comment: sv. I've read God is one, but he has many faces.