# What does Hinduism say about deities from other pantheons?

Tags: gods, other-religions

Does Hinduism have any views about gods from other pantheons/religions?

Comment: I am not an expert, and this is more of hearsay, but I have heard that the asuras used to be the pantheon of ancient Iran (maybe before Zoroaster too.) The shia muslims who have copied some of the Zorastrian/ancient Persian faith rituals have a festival called the 'Ahura Mazda'. Note that the Persian language doesn't have a letter for s and asura becomes ahura, sindhu becomes hindu, saptah becomes haptah, etc. Ancient Persian and Sanskrit have much in common, and it is even conjectured that the ancient Indians migrated to Persia, founding a different civilization there.

Comment: The asuras are the base superhuman creatures in Hinduism. Devil/demon are mistranslations. In the Hindu tradition, the asuras are like the devas, but the goodness is absent, and they are driven by base emotions like lust, greed, anger, etc.

Comment: Related : [Why all Avatar's and Grantha's references happened only in India and not elsewhere?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2828/647)